# I am trying to toggle between two images that appends on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle between two images and having trouble,

here is my Jquery:

```
$( ".games li" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).append( $( "<div id='img-toggle'><img class='favorite-not-banner' src='img/fav-not-saved.png' title='Add to favorites'><img class='favorite-banner' src='img/fav-saved.png' title='Remove from favorites'></div>" + "<a href='details.html'><p class='details'>View Details</p></a>").hide().fadeIn(600));
    }, function() {
        $( this ).find( ".favorite-banner" ).fadeOut(100);
        $( this ).find( ".details" ).fadeOut(100);
    }
);

$("#img-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

here is my css for the two classes:

```
.favorite-banner{
    bottom:58%;
    position:absolute;
    height:170px;
    right:60%;
}

.favorite-not-banner{
    bottom:58%;
    position:absolute;
    height:170px;
    right:60%;
    display:none;
 }
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typo error: `#img-toggle` inside `$("img-toggle")`

Comment: Is that a typo?  `src='img/fav-not-saved.png title=...` , there is no closing quote on the src.

Comment: yes these are typos, thank you! The problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use class instead of `id` for your appended `div` since `id` is unique:

```
$( this ).append( $( "<div class='img-toggle'><img class='favorite-not-banner' src='img/fav-not-saved.png title='Add to favorites'><img class='favorite-banner' src='img/fav-saved.png' title='Remove from favorites'></div>" + "<a href='details.html'><p class='details'>View Details</p></a>").hide().fadeIn(600));
```

Also, because your `div` are dynamically generated, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$('body').on('click','.img-toggle',function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

Event delegation will help you to attach click event to these newly added `.img-toggle` elements.